# Centering bxslider jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I am having difficulties centering the bxslider plugin within my html page.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Everry - Customise Now Proto</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#slider1').bxSlider();
          });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Customise Now Prototype</h1>
<div align = "center" id="slider1">
  <div>Slide one content</div>
  <div>Slide two content</div>
  <div>Slide three content</div>
  <div>And so on...</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    text-align: center; 
}

#slider1 {
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    liststyle: none;
}
```

It appears to be off centre though. Here is the url:

http://everry.com/new/customise/customisenow.html

I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#bx-wrapper  {margin:0 auto; width:700px;}
```

The slider plugin transforms you HTML, so dont use the slider container for centering :)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore. the width styles are added as in-line styling. It's driving me nuts. I don't want to have to use `!important`. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you give a link to a demo... You should still be able to create a container outside it :)

Comment: Note:  CSS should always be implemented in an external CSS stylesheet, not the body of your document, as informed in bxslider [site](http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-2)

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the stupid calculated margins and widths. This plugin is great but they are sloppy with their implementation and documentation. Just plug in your image widths below where I have 940 and this should fix your issue with the "off-center" problem.

```
.bx-wrapper, .bx-window {
    margin:0 auto; width:940px !important;
}

.pager{
    width:940px !important; 
}

#slider1 li{
    margin-left:0px !important;
}
```